# Умиляться — кем, с кого и на кого?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Глядя на кого-то, я умиляюсь" — как сказать иначе? "Я умиляюсь кем-то" или как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Умиляться кем-чем/кому-чему/на кого-что/над кем-чем
(Розенталь. Словарь управления)
Глядя на малыша, умиляюсь ему /им/ его улыбкой